Unexpect SwiftUI NavigationStack Behavior
How would I go about initializing a navigationpath with a already populated data array? For example I might want to load in path the user have previously navigated through. I'm trying to use this implementation but can't seem to understand why this throws an warning when compiled and ran.
Error:
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Code:
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct ControlView: View {

    @State var path = NavigationPath([1])

    var body: some View {
        // Defualt screen
        ZStack {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                EmptyView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { index in
                        Text("Index: \(index)")
                    }
            }

        }
    }

}

#if DEBUG

    struct DummyControlView: View {

        @StateObject private var appState = AppState()

        var body: some View {
            ControlView()
                .environmentObject(appState)
        }

    }

#endif

#Preview {
    DummyControlView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}


You could try populating the path in .onAppear instead

thats exactly what I thought. The problem is that using onappear causes all the children elements of the path to also be called. So all of their respective onappear functions are also called, which causes issues if you have env variables.

I wouldn't worry about "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints". SwiftUI often produces conflicting constraints. It's not useful to know why it does that. Are there any other undesirable behaviours?

I ended up with some hacky solution using onAppear, I know the constraint error is just a warning but its frustrating regardless.
